# AngularJS - Duas funções em apenas um arquivo

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu gostaria de colocar no mesmo arquivo as duas funções abaixo, mas quando faço isso, a segunda função (`notebooks`) deixa de responder.

Arquivo `App.js`:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);

module.controller('myCtrl', function ($window, $scope) {
    $scope.myFunction = function (item) {
        var url = String(window.location);
        url = url.substr(0, String($window.location.href).indexOf("www") + 4);
        $window.location.href = url + item.mmyurl;

    }
});


 })();
```

Outro arquivo `exemplo.js`:

```
function NotebookListCtrl($scope) {
$scope.notebooks = [
{"name": "Lenovo",
 "procesor": "Intel i5",
 "age": 2011},
{"name": "Toshiba",
 "procesor": "Intel i7",
 "age": 2010},
{"name": "Toshiba",
 "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
 "age": 2008},
{"name": "HP",
 "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
 "age": 2012},
{"name": "Acer",
 "procesor": "AMD",
 "age": 2006},
{"name": "Lenovo",
 "procesor": "Intel i5",
 "age": 2009},
{"name": "Toshiba",
 "procesor": "Intel i7",
 "age": 2008},
{"name": "Lenovo",
 "procesor": "Intel i5",
 "age": 2011},
{"name": "Toshiba",
 "procesor": "Intel i7",
 "age": 2010},
{"name": "Toshiba",
 "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
 "age": 2008},
{"name": "HP",
 "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
 "age": 2012},
{"name": "Acer",
 "procesor": "AMD",
 "age": 2006},
{"name": "Lenovo",
 "procesor": "Intel i5",
 "age": 2009},
{"name": "Toshiba",
 "procesor": "Intel i7",
 "age": 2008},
{"name": "Lenovo",
 "procesor": "Intel i5",
 "age": 2011},
{"name": "Toshiba",
 "procesor": "Intel i7",
 "age": 2010},
{"name": "Toshiba",
 "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
 "age": 2008},
{"name": "HP",
 "procesor": "Intel core 2 duo",
 "age": 2012},
{"name": "Acer",
 "procesor": "AMD",
 "age": 2006},
{"name": "Lenovo",
 "procesor": "Intel i5",
 "age": 2009},
{"name": "Toshiba",
 "procesor": "Intel i7",
 "age": 2008}
 ];
  $scope.orderList = "name";
    }
```

Eu quero juntar estes dois arquivos num só. Estou usando o framework **Onsen UI**.

```
<body>
    <div id="notebooks" ng-app ng-controller="NotebookListCtrl">
        <input type="text" id="query" ng-model="query"/>
        <select ng-model="orderList">
            <option value="name">By name</option>
            <option value="-age">Newest</option>
            <option value="age">Oldest</option>
        </select>
        <ul id="notebook_ul">
            <li ng-repeat="notebook in notebooks | filter:query | orderBy: orderList">
                name: {{notebook.name}}<br/>
                procesor: {{notebook.procesor}}<br/>
                <div class="right top">{{notebook.age}}</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <span>Number of notebooks: {{notebooks.length}}</span>
    </div>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você definir os valores do $scope do notebook fora de uma function. Do modo como você fez, seria necessário 'chama-la' para poder gerar os valores.

Ou seja, você deveria fazer assim:

```
function NotebookListCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.notebooks = [
        {"name": "Lenovo","procesor": "Intel i5","age": 2011},
        {.. restante aqui ..}
        {"name": "Toshiba","procesor": "Intel i7","age": 2008}
    ];
    $scope.orderList = "name";
}
NotebookListCtrl($scope);
```

Mas para simplificar o código, como ele já possui a array que você deseja, você pode integrar tudo em um controller da seguinte maneira:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);

    module.controller('myCtrl', function ($window, $scope) {
        $scope.myFunction = function (item) {
            var url = String(window.location);
            url = url.substr(0, String($window.location.href).indexOf("www") + 4);
            $window.location.href = url + item.mmyurl;
        };

        $scope.notebooks = [
            {"name": "Lenovo","procesor": "Intel i5","age": 2011},
            {.. restante aqui ..}
            {"name": "Toshiba","procesor": "Intel i7","age": 2008}
        ];
        $scope.orderList = "name";

    });

})();
```

Veja se funciona.

E conseguiu compreender a lógica?

Comment: 1. E conseguiu compreender a lógica? Sim entendi , sua explicação foi excelente,  2.Veja se funciona; Não sei se é ainda, algum erro meu ou por eu estar usando o Onsen ui (talvez conflito) .. ms não funcionou fiz uma cópia do arquivo exemplo  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103204235/Teste%20controles%20angular%20js.rar

Comment: Mas chega a aparecer algum erro no console.log?

Comment: Estou usando visual studio cordova (template) portanto passa direto

Comment: ele roda no navegador, da pra testar usando o browser e o notepad

Comment: É, ai eu não vou saber como te ajudar, pois trabalho com angularJs somente. Mas a lógica da função é aquela. Tente dar um console.log($scope.notebooks); bem antes de fechar o controller e veja se ele aparece os valores, o que provavelmente vai aparecer. Se não aparecer, deve ter algum erro ou conflito mesmo.

Comment: mas o projeto é puro angular js. só é criado dentro do visual studio. retirando os arquivos da ide fica so angular e html. como deixei no arquivo

Comment: Ok. Mas o que ele não está funcionando exatamente? Não mostra a lista de notebooks? Não faz a ordem correta? Tente fazer o log como comentei e passe as informações depois, explicando certinho o que está havendo

Comment: Agora deu , kkk  descobri o erro valeu foi sua ajuda

Comment: Ok. Boa sorte com desenvolvimento! =D

Answer (score 0):

Erro :   `<div id="notebooks" ng-app ng-controller="NotebookListCtrl">`
Alterando para   `<div id="notebooks" ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">` funcionou